# How do I achieve this effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration

Been trying to achieve this effect, how does one do it?

[image: the effect I want]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. As applicable, illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples.

Comment: Do you have to use Illustrator for that at all?

Comment: @TheDefinitionist although it could be done essentially anywhere, let's not make the scope of this question _broader_.  Check [ask] to learn more about asking good questions.

Comment: Relax, I was just simply asking. No need to jump on it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a specific effect, but instead a single leaf-looking shape, duplicated 3 times with colors adjusted and opacity probably set to 'Multiply'. There is no 'click-there-to-do-this' solution, it is most likely done manually.

Answer (score 1):

We do not know how transparent the presented shapes are. That makes blending mode speculations a little unsure. If you want some certain colors, you can input them directly:

[image]

There are three overlapping blue shapes. The overlapping zones are separated by applying Pathfinder panel > Divide and ungrouping.

The black strokes are removed. The zones have got their fill colors with the color picker from your example. In the right there's added on the top a rectangle with partially transparent gradient fill.

If you are going to export the result as PNG, the strokes would be useful. They should have the same colors as the fill colors. That's because otherwise the seams in the export easily could have 1 pixel wide transparent zone due the antialiasing in the rasterization. The strokes would cover the gaps.